# Inner product of $\mathcal{C}^r$ functions with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, inner-products, stochastic-pde

Context: [these notes](http://www.hairer.org/notes/Regularity.pdf), page 7, last paragraph (between equations 2.7 and 2.8).

> Given the $\mathcal{C}^r$ function with compact support $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$, we define
>   $$\varphi_x^n:=2^{nd/2}\varphi(2^n(\cdot -x)).$$
>
> Next, for some $\mathcal{C}^r$ function with compact support $\psi$, we try to bound
>
> $$|\langle\varphi_x^n,\psi\rangle|.$$

Substituting in the definition of $\varphi_x^n$, we get

$$|\langle\varphi(2^n(\cdot -x)),\psi\rangle|$$
$$= 2^{nd/2}|\int \varphi(2^n(\cdot -x))\psi|$$
Since both $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are integrable and with compact support, I would expect the integral to be bounded. Like this, I would obtain

$$|\langle\varphi_x^n,\psi\rangle| \lesssim 2^{nd/2}.$$

However, the paper gives

$$|\langle\varphi_x^n,\psi\rangle| \lesssim 2^{-nd/2}.$$

Why might that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the paper is a far better majoration. A change of variable will help us to get it.

$$\int_{\Bbb{R}^d } \varphi(2^n(y-x)) \psi(y) dy =  \int_{\Bbb{R}^d } \varphi(y-2^nx) \psi(\frac{y}{2^n}) (2^{-n})^d dy$$

Now $\psi$ is bounded, and $\varphi$ is bounded with compact support $K$, so

$$ \left| \int_{\Bbb{R}^d } \varphi(2^n(y-x)) \psi(y) dy  \right| =  \left| \int_{\Bbb{R}^d } \varphi(y-2^nx) \psi(2^{-n}y) 2^{-nd} dy  \right|$$

$$=  \left| \int_{K+2^nx } \varphi(y-2^nx) \psi(2^{-n}y) 2^{-nd} dy  \right|$$

$$\leq 2^{-nd} \int_{K+2^nx} \|\varphi\|_\infty \| \psi \|_\infty dy$$

$$\leq 2^{-nd} \mu(K) \|\varphi\|_\infty \| \psi \|_\infty$$

And if you multiply this by $2^{\frac{nd}{2}}$, you get the given coefficient

Comment: thanks for your answer. When you change the domain of the integral to $K+2^n x$, why are you allowed to shift it by $2^nx$? I get that $\varphi$ will only be nonzero in that subset, but what about $\psi$, whose argument doesn't get shifted?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt : it doesn't matter what's "inside" $\psi$, as you majorate it by its supremum norm.

Comment: but what about before you take the supremum norm, when you write $\left| \int_{\Bbb{R}^d } \varphi(y-2^nx) \psi(2^{-n}y) 2^{-nd} dy  \right| =  \left| \int_{K+2^nx } \varphi(y-2^nx) \psi(2^{-n}y) 2^{-nd} dy  \right|$? How do we know they're equal, when $\psi(2^{-n}y)$ may be nonzero outside of $K+2^nx$?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt : but if $\varphi(y-2^nx)$ is zero outside $K+2^nx$, obviously, the product with anything else is zero too !

Comment: Oh yeah, it's obvious. Thanks again for your answer (and patience)!